# Javascript dynamic callback functions

Tags: javascript, callback

I am trying to design a function that will accept different functions as argument (callbacks). These functions can have different number of arguments. Is there a way I can execute the callback directly without bothering the number of arguments

For example :

```
function displayDialog(callBack)
 {
                   callBack();
 };
```

This function can be executed as follwing:

```
displayDialog(myFunction);
```

Where myFunction is

```
function myFunction(){}
```

or function `myFunction(a,b){}

Comment: then how to decide what parameters has to be sent to the callback

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? You can look at the arguments array in the callback function (it's always there), and it will contain all the arguments which the callback function was called with. Then you decide what you want to do with them. If you want to execute the function WITH an arbitrary amount of arguments, you should use apply (callback.apply(.. , [.. , ..]))

edit: the arguments array is not an actual array though

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all, for your answers. I tried using the apply and it worked. Here is what I did:

```
    function caller()
    {
        var args = ['a', 'b']; 
        displayDialog(myFunction, args);
    }
```

and in displayDialog function:

```
function displayDialog(callBack, args)
{
      callBack.apply(null, args);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function, that have args set in the declaration, without supplying any arguments. The parameters will be `undefined` in the function though, so do a check if they are actually set before using them.

Example:

```
function callbackFunction(arg1, arg2) {
    // First call, arg1 will be "a" and arg2 will be undefined
    // Second call, arg1 and arg2 will be undefined
    // Third call, arg1 will be "a" and arg2 will be "b"
    if(arg1 !== undefined) {
        // You can use arg1.
    }
    if(arg2 !== undefined) {
        // You can use arg2
    }
    // Easiest way to handle this is to set it to a default value if its not set:
    // (usually done at the top of the function).
    arg1 = arg1 === undefined ? "default" : arg1;
    arg2 = arg2 === undefined ? "default" : arg2;
}

callbackFunction("a");
callbackFunction();
callbackFunction("a", "b");
```

---

You can also skip using arguments in the function declaration and then use the [argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) list:

```
function callbackFunction() {
    for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++) {
        console.log(arguments[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: if I use args, i would still need to know the parameters for those functions. Like I will have to do args[0] or args[1]. But I don't know how may arguments it can have.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the arguments to a callback are dictated by the code that calls it. That is, your `displayDialog` function would document what arguments it gives to the callback.

If someone using `displayDialog` needs information in their callback that `displayDialog` doesn't provide, that's the *caller's* problem. They have a couple of different things they can do:

1. Make their callback close over the information they need
2. Use `Function#bind` or similar to [curry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) the arguments into their function

Here's an example of #1:

```js
// Documentation: The callback will be called with the
// number 42
function displayDialog(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback(42); //
  }, 35);
}

// A function using displayDialog
function useIt() {
  var str = "I'm some information the callback needs";
  displayDialog(function(arg) {
    snippet.log("arg = " + arg);
    snippet.log("str = " + str);
  });
}

snippet.log("Calling useIt");
useIt();
snippet.log("useIt completed");
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Here's an example of #2:

```js
// Documentation: The callback will be called with the
// number 42
function displayDialog(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback(42); //
  }, 35);
}

// A function using displayDialog
function useIt() {
  displayDialog(function(arg0, arg1) {
    snippet.log("arg0 = " + arg0);
    snippet.log("arg1 = " + arg1);
  }.bind(null, "I'm a curried argument"));
}

snippet.log("Calling useIt");
useIt();
snippet.log("useIt completed");
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks!! I could do it using fn.apply(null, args) function.

Comment: @user1000397: You *could*, if you had an array of arguments you needed to call the function with, instead of discrete arguments. If you have discrete arguments, just call the function normally: `fn(arg0, arg1);`